# Why is $\sum_{k=2}^n{{n-2}\choose{k-2}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

> Show that $$B_n(f_2)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)f_2+\frac{1}{n}f_1, \\\text{ where } (B_n(f))(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\cdot {n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}, \text{ for } x\in[0,1]\\\text{ and }f_0(x)=1, f_1(x)=x, f_2(x)=x^2$$

Background: I am trying to prove the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, using Bernstein polynomials. In order to do this, my book establishes a few lemmas first in order to prove Bernstein's Theorem. This is one of those lemmas, but I am having a little trouble concluding its proof.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
&B_n(f_2)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\\
&\text{We rewrite } \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2{n\choose k} \text{ as follows:}\\
&  \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2{n\choose k}\\
&=\frac{k^2n!}{(n-k)!k!n^2}\\
&=\frac{k(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!\dot n}\\
&=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right){n-1 \choose{k-1}}\\
&=\frac{k-1}{n}{{n-1}\choose k-1}+\frac{1}{n}{n-1\choose{k-1}}\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)(k-2)!}\right)+\frac{1}{n}{n-1\choose{k-1}}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!(n-1)}\right)+\frac{1}{n}{n-1\choose{k-1}}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{(n-2)}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}\right)+\frac{1}{n}{n-1\choose{k-1}}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){n-2 \choose{k-2}}+\frac{1}{n}{n-1\choose{k-1}}\\
&\text{Plugging this in we get:}\\
&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){{n-2}\choose{k-2}}+\frac{1}{n}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}\right)(x^k(1-x)^{n-k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){{n-2}\choose{k-2}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}+\frac{1}{n}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){{n-2}\choose{k-2}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{k=2}^n{{n-2}\choose{k-2}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\\
\end{align}

And this is where I am stuck. I need to conclude the last line is equal to:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)x^2+\frac{1}{n}x$$

If the "choose" brackets had $n$ and $k$ instead of $n-2,k-2,n-1,$or $k-1$, I would use the binomial theorem, but since they're those, I'm not sure how to apply the Binomial Theorem (if that's even what I'm supposed to do?)

Thanks for reading this far and for any assistance.

Comment: Divide by $x^2$ and see the binomial formula for $\left(x+\left(1-x\right)\right)^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^n k{n\choose k}x^k(1-y)^{n-k}$$
and
$$g(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1){n\choose k}x^k(1-y)^{n-k}$$
then easily we see that

$$f(x,y)=x\frac{d}{dx}(1+x-y)^n$$
and
$$g(x,y)=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x-y)^n$$
and notice that your desired result is just

$$\frac{g(x,x)+f(x,x)}{n^2}$$